# How to read a local JSON file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I am following a tutorial on YouTube but I couldn't make it run. Basically I have a `country.json` file.and I am trying to retrieve data inside it. What is wrong here??

This is how `country.json` file looks like

```
{
  "name": "Germany",
  "capital": "Berlin",
  "pop": "some value"
}
```

JavaScript

```
var container = $("div.container");
$("input#get").click(function () {
  $.ajax({
    type: "Get",
    url: "country.json",
    dataType: "json",
    successs: function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (index, item) {
        $.each(item, function (key, value) {
          container.append(key + " : " + value + "</br>");
        });
        container.appendChild("<br/><br>")
      });
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="container"></div>
<div id="form-area">
  <h2>Get</h2>
  <input type="submit" id="get" value="get">
</div>
```

Comment: Isn't datatype waits a mime type? I always used `dataType: "application/json"`. Also use the full url to the file, but be careful, that file must be in a public directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get it like this:-

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="container"></div>
<div id="form-area">
    <h2>Get</h2>
    <input type="submit" id="get" value="get">
</div>
</body>
</html>

 <script type="text/javascript">
var container = $(".container"); //check change here
$("#get").click(function () { //check change here
    $.getJSON( "country.json", function( data ) {
       var myhtml = ''; // create an empty variable
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            myhtml += key + ' : ' + value + '</br>'; // append data to variable

        });
      container.append( myhtml); // append the whole data (variable) to div
    });
});
</script>
```

Output (on my local browser):- http://prntscr.com/cq2jjt

Note:- to read data from json file  `$.getJSON()` is required.

Check more detail:- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Comment: @aliak  glad to help you. :):)

Answer (score 1):

You need `https:\\` to run the Ajax, Simply in local file it will not work. Specially in Chrome. Use the `Apache server` in your machine and add all your file. And run the application through `localhost`. Ajax call will fire. Before to that, Try the same application in Firefox one. Firefox might do the ajax locally.

Answer (score 1):

we can acheive this by using jquery library..

```
$.getJSON( "ajax/country.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
       items.push( "<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>" );
  });
  $('#form-area').html(items.join(""));
});
```